# Vue js put all text into a json file and import it

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I want to import the json file I think I did that but I have a chat bot I want the questions and the answers in a json file but it doens't work.

It work without the json file I put all the data and put it in the same file but it is not readebly that is why I want to put all the data into the json file.

**Template**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container max" ref="scroll">
            <div class="container con">
                <div class="row ml-0 mt-3">
                    <p>{{this.file.welkom}}</p>
                </div>
               <p id="chatLog" class="chatLog font-weight-bold"></p><br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-4">
            <div class="col">
                <input id="userBox" class="inputChat" type="text" @keyup.enter="talk()" v-model="msg" required>
            </div>
            <div type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary mt-2 ml-2" @click="talk()">Send<img class="sendIcon" src="@/assets/icons/send.png"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**This is the script file**

```
<script>
// eslint-disable-next-line
import json from './info.json';
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            title: 'Chat bot',
            file: this.json,
            msg: ''
        }
    },
    head: {
        title: function () {
            return {
                inner: this.title
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        talk() {
            var user = this.msg;
            document.getElementById('chatLog').innerHTML += user + '<br>';
            if (user != '') {
                if (user in this.file) {
                    document.getElementById('chatLog').innerHTML += this.file[user] + "<br>" + "<br>";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('chatLog').innerHTML += 'I can\'t answer your question, type "help" I can only help you with that or you can go to the Faq page...<br>' + '<br>';
                }
            } else {
                alert('Type text in');
            }
            console.log(this.msg);
            this.msg = '';
            const chatLogDiv = this.$refs.scroll;
            chatLogDiv.scrollTop = chatLogDiv.scrollHeight
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**And my info.json file**

```
[
    {
        "welkom": "Welcome I will help you to answer your questions. If you want more info type 'help'.",
        "help": "Working...",
        "how do you login": "If you are on the 'Homepage' you see on the top a 'Login' button click on it, sign in with your email and password and you logged in.",
        "how do you register": "1. Click on 'login' on the navbar. 2. On the right side you see a 'SIGN UP' button click on the button and you can register.",
        "add internship": "1. You need a account and you need to be logged in.' + '<br>' +'2. When you logged in you see above your email on the right side you see 'Add internship' ' +'click on it.' + '<br>' +'3. Then you see some empty field you need to fill with your company information ' +'4. You can see how it is on the 'Preview design' and if everthing is good click on 'Add internship'.",
        "edit a internship": "1. Go to your 'internship page'. Their you see a edit button if you click on it you can edit ' + 'your internship information."
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a quick glance at your code:

```
file: this.json,
```

should be like below, 'this' refers to the Vue instance

```
file: json,
```

Your json should look like below ideally (without the []), so you can do `this.file[user]` (otherwise, because it's an array, you'll have to do `this.file[0][user]`).

```
{
    "welkom": "Welcome I will help you to answer your questions. If you want more info type 'help'.",
    "help": "Working...",
    "how do you login": "If you are on the 'Homepage' you see on the top a 'Login' button click on it, sign in with your email and password and you logged in.",
    "how do you register": "1. Click on 'login' on the navbar. 2. On the right side you see a 'SIGN UP' button click on the button and you can register.",
    "add internship": "1. You need a account and you need to be logged in.' + '<br>' +'2. When you logged in you see above your email on the right side you see 'Add internship' ' +'click on it.' + '<br>' +'3. Then you see some empty field you need to fill with your company information ' +'4. You can see how it is on the 'Preview design' and if everthing is good click on 'Add internship'.",
    "edit a internship": "1. Go to your 'internship page'. Their you see a edit button if you click on it you can edit ' + 'your internship information."
}
```